# Identities for Kronecker delta and alternating unit tensor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6AMN.png]

How I can prove this equations?
Please help me...
I can solve it.
$$\sum_j\sum_k \varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{hjk} = 2\delta_{ih}$$
$$\sum_k \varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{mnk}= \delta_{im} \delta_{jn} -\delta_{in} \delta_{jm}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, just note that if $i \neq j$, for each term in the sum, there will be repeated indices in one or both factors, and hence the sum is $0$.  However if $i=j$, you will always have exactly two terms in the sum of form $1\times1$ and $-1\times -1$.  Hence $2\delta_{ij}$ is correct.

The reasoning for the second equation is similar, though longer.